# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator / Call fault sequence from API's inSequence

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

Using Enterprise Integrator 6.6.0, how can I call a fault sequence in case some kind of error happens in an api's inSequence?
For example, I want to parse as an integer a $url parameter, but in case it's not a parsable integer I get only an error in the console

```
[2021-08-05 10:00:46,669] ERROR {PropertyMediator} - Unknown type : INTEGER for the property mediator or the property value cannot be converted into the specified type. java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "780jk"
```

but the client still gets a 200

Answer (score 1):

In your api resource definition, are you including a `faultSequence` element?

```xml
<api name="API_NAME" context="URI_PATH_OF_API" [hostname="HOST_NAME_OF_SERVER"]  [port="PORT_NUMBER"]>
    <resource [methods="GET|POST|PUT|DELETE|OPTIONS|HEAD|PATCH"] [uri-template="URI_TEMPLATE"|url-mapping="URL_MAPPING"]>
      <inSequence>
        ...
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         ...
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence>
         ...
      </faultSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

You can check more about it [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Working+with+APIs)

Inside that fault sequence you can return to the client the HTTP code or message of your choice.

```xml
<property name="HTTP_SC" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="404"/>
<respond/>
```